# Jquery forms - can I add inputs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm trying to add these two or more inputs in jquery, to give me the output of both input values (5 + 2) times a "product" amount ($50.25).
How can I add all inputs, without assigning any class or id to these inputs?
Can you please guide me here.

```
<input type="text" value="5" /> <input type="text" value="2" />
<h3></h3>

<script>
$("input").keyup(function () {
    var value = parseFloat($(this).val());
    var item_price = parseFloat("50.25");

    $("h3").text(value * item_price);
   }).keyup();
</script>
```

This code outputs the most recent edited field. For example, if I were to switch the first field to a value of 2 the total will change to "100.5", then changing the other field will change the total based on That field, not both.

I tried inserting the key listener into $("input").each() selector, but obviously something snapped in the code, since it didn't return any results.

```
$("input").each(function() {
    value += parseFloat($(this).val());
    $("input").keyup(function () {
    var value = parseFloat($(this).val());
    var item_price = parseFloat("50.25");

    $("h3").text(value * item_price);
}).keyup();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be what you're looking for. Put all of the calculations in a function, and just bind that function to the keypress. You'll also probably want to call that function right away to do initial calculations as I have done in my demo.

See Live Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/za2vJ/4/

Answer (score 0):

Your scoping is incorrect:

```
$("input").keyup(function() {
    var itemPrice = 50.25;
    var total = 0.0;
    $("input").each(function() {
       total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    $("h3").html(total * itemPrice);
}).keyup();
```

Comment: Nope, that won't work. Since you are adding to 'total' every time you edit a field. Additionally, why in gods green earth would you waste resources by adding an extra unneeded var, var total? What if I also wan't to output the raw number?

Comment: @Yisroel So let me get this straight... you came here asking for help, but you're knowledgeable enough that you would take to being condescending? The only reason this may not do what you want is because your question was phrased poorly and I seem to have misunderstood. This is the exact same code suggested by the other two answers here. Proof is in the pudding: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lthibodeaux/8bDgL/)**

Answer (score 0):

The key point is to loop thru the inputs and add their values.

```
var totalInput = 0;
$("input").keyup(function () {
    //zero out the global var totalInput
    totalInput = 0;
    $("input").each(function(){
        //for each input, add value to global totalInput
        totalInput += $(this).val()
    });

    //setup price
    var item_price = parseFloat("50.25");

    //display price times totalInput
    $("h3").text(totalInput * item_price);
});
```